# Quitting BackgroundWorker using flag

Tags: c#, multithreading, backgroundworker

Imagine I Have such code:

```
 private bool flag = false;
 public SomeClass()
 {
     public void setup()
    {
        worker = new BackgroundWorker();
        worker.DoWork += worker_DoWork;

        if(!worker.IsBusy)
            worker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        if(flag == true)
          return;
        //whatever You want the background thread to do...
        SomeClass.SomeStaticMethodWhichHasLoopInside();
    }
}
```

When user clicks Exit button in my application I can set `flag=true` inside - is this the right way to stop the thread started by `BackgroundWorker`?
I want to do this only when application wants to quit - so that I stop the thread. Or it will be automatically killed?

Comment: The best practice is written in [Sriram Sakthivel's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30231268/2144232) hower I must mention, that your solution might work if you mark `flag` as `volatile`. Without the `volatile` keyword - which prevents the variable from being cached - the optimiser might store the `flag` of your thread in L2 or a register while the `flag` of your main thread is stored in the RAM, so your without `volatile` your thread might never get informed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. Don't do that. It will not work as expected. Your `flag` field isn't even declared as `volatile`; it is possible that true value of the field isn't flushed to the memory yet. Other thread will still see the `flag` to be false because it caches its own copy of the value and your `BackgroundWorker` may never end.

Instead, just call [BackgroundWorker.CancelAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.cancelasync%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and check for [BackgroundWorker.CancellationPending](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.cancellationpending%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) boolean inside the `DoWork` event handler.

```
private void OnExit(..)
{
    worker.CancelAsync();
}
```

So your DoWork method will become

```
void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    while(!worker.CancellationPending)
    {
        //whatever You want the background thread to do...
    }
}
```

If you don't have a loop, you need to check `CancellationPending` property time to time.

```
void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    if(worker.CancellationPending)
        return;
    //Do something..
    if(worker.CancellationPending)
        return;
    //Do some other thing..
    if(worker.CancellationPending)
        return;
    //Do something else..
}
```

> I want to do this only when application wants to quit - so that I stop
>   the thread. Or it will be automatically killed?

It will be killed automatically by the CLR since the thread is a Background Thread. But, don't rely on this fact because we don't know what your thread will be executing at the time CLR kills the thread. For example, it might have been writing a file in which case you'd be left with the corrupted file.

Consequences can be even worse, so it is always recommended to stop your threads yourself gracefully.

> Question asked in comments: How can I cancel when the loop is in some
>   other method?

It seems you're using .Net4.5. You can take advantage of `CancellationTokenSource` and `CancellationToken`. Also you may consider using TPL and async-await features which will make your life a lot easier.

```
private CancellationTokenSource tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

private void OnExit(..)
{
    tokenSource.Cancel();
}

void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    //whatever You want the background thread to do...
    SomeClass.SomeStaticMethodWhichHasLoopInside(tokenSource.Token);
}

class SomeClass
{
    public static void SomeStaticMethodWhichHasLoopInside(CancellationToken token)
    {
        while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            //Do something
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is a loop inside a method which is called inside the `worker_Dowork` method - but that method is from another class - how do I refer to worker from that method? make `worker` static?

Comment: do you mean this: http://postimg.org/image/efldufscd/? Or this http://postimg.org/image/gefw4bu9f/ Please provide full code for the solution - I am a little bit new to C#

Comment: I have updated question how the thread looks like using `SomeStaticMethodWhichHasLoopInside` - please show answer how would I check that property from that method

Comment: Why can't I declare `worker` as static and check for `SomeClass.Static_worker.CancellationPending` from `SomeStaticMethodWhichHasLoopInside` -- looks easier ??

Comment: @user300455 That's not a good practice. I discourage the use of static. If you want, you may do it. But I recommend the right way which is right there in my answer.

Comment: So your solution will work even if I click exit *after* the `SomeStaticMethodWhichHasLoopInside`  has already been called and the `tokenSource` was already passed to it?. Why do you discourage with static? From other method I could check: `Class.static_worker.CancellationPending`

Comment: @user300455 It will work. Try it out. There are several reasons for discouraging static members. Refer [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7026507/why-are-static-variables-considered-evil) also there are many discussions about static. Just do a web search in this topic.